# Why does 1.0 not equal to 1.0 in tcl when using ==

Tags: floating-point, tcl

In the following code, I've encountered a strange phenomena. On on the runs on the line `if {$ma == $mb}` both `mb` and `ma` were equal `1.0`, but the if wasn't taken. When I've changed the `==` to `eq` or `[cequal $ma $mb]`, the if was taken.

Also, when I tried changing one of the variables with `1.0` (`if {$ma == 1.0}` and `if {$1.0 == $mb}`) the if wasn't taken as well, however an if with the expression `if {1.0 ==1.0}` is taken.

Another thing that happened to me after changing `==` to `eq` is that `0.0` and `-0.0` are not equal when using `eq`, but are equal when using `==`.

What is the source for those differences?

I'm aware that in floating point number comparison it's better to use a small epsilon to check if two numbers are really close to each other, but in this case the comparison is done to avoid division by zero.

Code:

```
proc geometry_intersect_two_sections {xa1 ya1 xa2 ya2 xb1 yb1 xb2 yb2} {
    if {($xa1 == $xa2) && ($xb1 == $xb2)} {
        return {}
    }

    if {!($xa1 == $xa2)} {
        set ma [expr (($ya1-$ya2)*1.0)/($xa1-$xa2)]
        set na [expr $ya1 - ($ma * 1.0 * $xa1)]
    }

    if {!($xb1 == $xb2)} {
        set mb [expr (($yb1-$yb2)*1.0)/($xb1-$xb2)]
        set nb [expr $yb1 - ($mb * 1.0 * $xb1)]
    }

    if {$xa1 == $xa2} {
        set retx [expr $xa1 * 1.0]
        set rety [expr $retx * 1.0 * $mb + $nb]
        if {($rety <= [max $yb1 $yb2]) && ($rety >= [min $yb1 $yb2]) && ($rety <= [max $ya1 $ya2]) && ($rety >= [min $ya1 $ya2]) && \
            ($retx <= [max $xb1 $xb2]) && ($retx >= [min $xb1 $xb2]) && ($retx <= [max $xa1 $xa2]) && ($retx >= [min $xa1 $xa2])} {ety]
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }

    if {$xb1 == $xb2} {
        set retx [expr $xb1 * 1.0]
        set rety [expr $retx * 1.0 * $ma + $na]
        if {($rety <= [max $yb1 $yb2]) && ($rety >= [min $yb1 $yb2]) && ($rety <= [max $ya1 $ya2]) && ($rety >= [min $ya1 $ya2]) && \
            ($retx <= [max $xb1 $xb2]) && ($retx >= [min $xb1 $xb2]) && ($retx <= [max $xa1 $xa2]) && ($retx >= [min $xa1 $xa2])} {
            return [list $retx $rety]
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }

    if {$mb == $ma} {
        return {}
    }

    set retx [expr 1.0 * ($na - $nb)/($mb - $ma)]
    set rety [expr 1.0 * ($ma * $retx) + $na]
    if {($rety <= [max $yb1 $yb2]) && ($rety >= [min $yb1 $yb2]) && ($rety <= [max $ya1 $ya2]) && ($rety >= [min $ya1 $ya2]) && \
        ($retx <= [max $xb1 $xb2]) && ($retx >= [min $xb1 $xb2]) && ($retx <= [max $xa1 $xa2]) && ($retx >= [min $xa1 $xa2])} {
        return [list $retx $rety]
    } else {
        return {}
    }
```

Comment: are you absolutely certain both variables had the literal value 1.0? Is it possible one of them had a value like 1.0000000001 and it was printing as 1.0 due to rounding?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I don't know, when I did `[set ma]` and `[puts $ma]` I got `1.0`, and `eq` did return true between them.

Comment: when you use `eq`, Tcl converts the values to a string, which throws away precision.

Comment: I note that you're using `expr` without putting braces around the expression, which is *enormously slower* as it forces reparsing of the expression each time through (just in case one of the arguments is `1+2+3*4-79` or whatever). Unless you need the reinterpretation, put the expression in braces and get it going fast. (It's much safer  too, as it makes a value like `[exit]` be a syntax error and not a call to end the process…)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IEEE floating point values (which Tcl uses internally because they are supported by your CPU hardware) are very well known to have the feature that they don't exactly represent values. To a first approximation anyway; they do represent values exactly as they have a fixed number of bits (64 for `double`, which is what Tcl uses) but the value that they represent could be slightly different to what you think it is (because many values can't be represented exactly in fixed number of binary digits, just as <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> is almost but not exactly 0.333333333 in decimal; it's the *exact* same issue, but in another number base).

Tcl takes some *limited* steps to work around this issue for display purposes; since 8.5 it renders floating point numbers with the minimum number of digits required to get the exact value out again, and in 8.4 and before it simply uses a smaller number of digits when printing a number out (up to 15 decimal digits instead of the 17 that would be required for doing exact representation) where that's controllable via the magic `tcl_precision` variable. Do not set that variable though; it doesn't do what you need since it is all about the rendering of the value to a string, and not the value itself. Instead, you need to use a different (and very well known) strategy for equality: equal-within-epsilon.

```
# Magic value! This one is OK for values in the range of small integers
proc equal_float {a b {epsilon 1e-15}} {
    return [expr {abs($a - $b) < $epsilon}]
}
```

You'd then use it like this:

```
# Instead of: if {$x == 42.3} { ... }
if {[equal_float $x 42.3]} { ... }
```

Note that it is another consequence of this is that you should never use floating point numbers for iteration purposes, as that allows errors to accumulate and exceed the epsilon. Instead of going from 0 to 25 by steps of 0.1, go from 0 to 250 in integer steps and then derive the float value by multiplying by 0.1.

Answer (score 4):

To directly address your question, `==` will fail whenever the two numbers are not equal.

In your question you mention that `eq` gave a different result than `==`. This is due to the fact that `eq` causes the values to be converted to a string before the comparison is done. When floating point values are converted to strings, they must be rounded up to some value. In the case of two floating point numbers that fall within a certain range, they will be rounded to the same value, yielding the exact same string.

Answer (score 2):

`==` forces numeric comparison, while `eq` forces string comparison (and your `cequal` comes from Tclx, if memory serves me, and essentially has the same semantics as `eq`).

The problem with comparison floating point values for strict equality is flawed by design as these types do not hold precise values (contrary to integers).  One sensible approach to compare two floats is to define a certain (very small) constant, "epsilon", and see if the absolute value of their difference is less than that "epsilon".  If it's less, you declare that the two floats are the same, and not the same otherwise. A quick Google search turns up [this essay](http://www.infogoaround.org/JBook/FloatingComparison.pdf), and [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html), among other useful links.

Another approach is to try to stick to integers (by using appropriate upscaling and downscaling where appropriate to not under/over-flow).

Comment: Actually, floating point numbers hold precise values. Just not necessarily the precise values you were looking for.